# Show that $S(X)$ is abelian if and only if $|X|\le 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to prove that the symmetric group $S(X)$ is only abelian for sets $X$ with cardinality below $2$. But I only get as far as proving that $S_2$ is abelian, and I can provide examples of $S_3$ and higher of not being abelian, for not sufficient for a proof.

Also, I can prove it by using the principle that the symmetric group is abelian if it consists of disjoint permutations, but the proof is supposed to be done without ant knowledge of permutations.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

*Edit: Obviously it is sufficient to provide an example of $S_3$ not being abelian. Question answered!*

Comment: Why isn't it enough to show that $S_3$  is non-abelian?  After all, if $X$ contains at least $3$ elements then $S_3\subseteq S(X)$.

Comment: Since $S_n$ is the group of all permutations of a set with $n$ elements, I fail to see how you can expect to be able to prove whatsoever about it without any knowledge of permutations.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: $S_3\hookrightarrow S_m\cong S(X)$ for $m=|X|\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(12)(13)=(132)$ but $(13)(12)=(123)$.

Answer (score 1):

To show a group is non-abelian it is enough to find just one counterexample.

And every set of three or more members has at least one subset with exactly three members.

And within that subset, you have found an example.